# android simulate Recycler view on custom view

Tags: android

i'm trying to simulate `RecyclerView` items on my custom view. i like to create simple TimeLine view and `ListView` or `Recycler View` not good for this idea, for example:

[image]

basically How can i pick the layouts to root viewgroup? for create above custom layout

My xml view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.pishguy.timelineview.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup inclusionViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

        View child1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.child_layout1, null);
        View child2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.child_layout2, null);
        inclusionViewGroup.addView(child1);
        inclusionViewGroup.addView(child2);
    }
}
```

child_layout 1 and 2 are same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:background="#909090"
              android:layout_height="30dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ddddd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int placeholderId = R.id.reservedNamedId; // placeholderId==1
        ViewGroup placeholder = (ViewGroup)findViewById(placeholderId);
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            View child1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                    R.layout.child_layout1, null);
            child1.setId(i);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.reservedNamedId);

            child1.setLayoutParams(p);

            placeholder.addView(child1);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) ? You could use [onDrawOver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#onDrawOver) to draw your links on top of the items.